# java.io.FileNotFoundException issues with FileInputStream Class

Tags: android

I am in the process of writing an APP within Android. I want to pass a String into FileInputStream(). It compiles fine but once this is ran I get the exception thrown and the app quits. I have the String Variable formatted correctly.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
 // External storage 
    File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Desire this   
    String CompletePath = (Root + "/PIL_SYNECT_TEST_PLAN/Ready_for_Execution" +   gVTruckSpecificSubFolder + "/" + gVFileToBeUsed);

    // debug msg
    Log.i(TAG, "onClick  CompletePath ------------------------>:" + CompletePath);

    //InputStream stream this is the way I need it to be
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(CompletePath);

    // Not hardcode in a string. However this works but is not how this needs to be
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/PIL_SYNECT_TEST_PLAN/Ready_for_Execution/C5 Daily Inspection List.json");
```

Below is the Logcat message:

```
 02-15 14:25:51.928 23346 23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool    I/TomsMessage:      onClick      CompletePath ------------------------ >:/storage/emulated/0/PIL_SYNECT_TEST_PLAN/Ready_for_Execution/C-5 DV123/C5 Daily Inspection List.json
    02-15 14:25:51.928 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/PIL_SYNECT_TEST_PLAN/Ready_for_Execution/C-5 DV123/C5 Daily Inspection List.json
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:  (No such file or directory)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:99)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:256)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6257)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11149)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23705)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    02-15 14:25:51.929 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    02-15 14:25:51.930 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    02-15 14:25:51.930 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    02-15 14:25:51.930 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    02-15 14:25:51.930 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
    02-15 14:25:51.930 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    02-15 14:25:51.930 23346-23346/com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                 Process: com.example.t0028919.person_in_looptesttool, PID: 23346
```

Comment: You're not escaping the spaces in your file path.  You might want to try to use the Uri class to sanitize your Uri, by using the Uri.parse(...) method first.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Not needed. That advice was nonsense.

Comment: You requested permissions in manifest file? And for Android 6+ added code so the user was asked to  confirm those permissions?

Comment: agree with @greenapps, check for runtime permission. And you need to check this code: `String CompletePath = (Root + "/PIL_SYNECT_TEST_PLAN/Ready_for_Execution" +   gVTruckSpecificSubFolder + "/" + gVFileToBeUsed);`. It seem missing a "/".

Comment: @greenapps explain further?  I know it's not as simple as Uri.parse(), it's more of a hint ;P try it.  Also, wouldn't a SecurityException be thrown if runtime permissions weren't there?

Comment: Here are my permissions:

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Thanks everyone I think I got it... I found when using a spinner

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayTruckList);

Comment: This ArrayAdapter was using arrayTruckList and this ArrayList I unintentionally added a "\n" So I could see each entry easily. I forgot to take it out and caused myself hours of heartache. I was so surprised the Logcat did not show this escape sequence for line feed.

Comment: arrayTruckList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            AllFiles = (files[i].getName() );//+ "\n"); <---- Caused hours of time to diagnose  

            // Collect current set of trucks from the folder dynamically;
            arrayTruckList.add(AllFiles);
        }